# RegEx for replacing and adding attributes to an HTML tag

Tags: php, regex, actionscript-3

Given the following code :

```
<body>
  <img src="source.jpg" />
  <p>
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="hello" alt="nothing" />
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="world"/>
  </p>
</body>
```

What's the best way - using a regular expression (or better?) - to replace it so it becomes this:

```
<body>
  <img src="source.jpg" id="img_0" />
  <p>
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="img_1"  alt="nothing" />
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="img_2"/>
  </p>
</body>
```

In other words :

- All the `<image />` tags all gets populated by an `id` attribute.
- The `id` attribute should contain an incremented attribute (this is not really the problem though as its just part of the replace procedure)

I guess two passes are needed, one to remove all the existent `id` attributes and another to populate with new ones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Also I would recommend a slightly more stringent `regexp` than those suggested so far - what if your page contains an `<img />` tag that does *not* contain an `id` attribute?

```
$page = '
<body>
  <img src="source.jpg" />
  <p>
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="hello" alt="nothing" />
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="world"/>
  </p>
</body>';

function my_callback($matches)
{
    static $i = 0;
    return $matches[1]."img_".$i++;
}

print preg_replace_callback('/(<img[^>]*id\s*=\s*")([^"]*)/', "my_callback", $page);
```

Which produces the following for me:

```
<body>
  <img src="source.jpg" />
  <p>
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="img_0" alt="nothing" />
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="img_1"/>
  </p>
</body>
```

The `regexp` has two capturing groups, the first we preserve, the second we replace. I've used lots of negative character classes (e.g. `[^>]*` = up to closing `>`) to make sure that `<img />` tags arn't *required* to have `id` attributes.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$data = <<<DATA
<body>
  <img src="source.jpg" />
  <p>
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="hello" alt="nothing" />
    <img src="source.jpg" id ="world"/>
  </p>
</body>
DATA;

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->strictErrorChecking = true;
$doc->standalone = true;
$doc->xmlStandalone = true;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NOERROR);

$sNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img");

$id = 0;
foreach($sNode as $searchNode)
{
  $searchNode->setAttribute('id', "img_$id");
  $doc->importNode($searchNode);
  $id++;
}

$result = $doc->saveHTML();
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

With appropriate escaping (that I can never remember without trial and error), and something to increment the img_number, you want to replace something like this:

(<img .*?)(?:id=".*")?(.*?/>)

with something like this this:

\1 id="img_$i"\2

Comment: Not sure if you wrote that before I fixed the syntax...  the ?: makes the middle group non-capturing, which speeds regex execution on fast platforms.

Answer (score 0):

try below function once, if attribute not found then it will add it in html tag

```
<?php 

/**
     * add Attribute in HTML Tag...
     * 
     * for Ex:- $htmlStr = <a href="http://saveprice.in">http://saveprice.in/</a> , $tagName = a, $attributeName = target, $attributevalue = _blank 
     * output will :- <a href="http://saveprice.in" target="_blank">saveprice.in</a>
     * 
     * then above $htmlStr = #above output, $tagName = a, $attributeName = style, $attributevalue = color:red;
     * output will :- <a href="http://saveprice.in" target="_blank" style="color:red;">saveprice.in</a>
     *
     * @param string $htmlStr // html string
     * @param string $tagname // html tag name
     * @param string $attributeName // html tag attribute name like class, id, style etc...
     * @param string $attributeValue // value of attribute like, classname, idname, style-property etc...
     * 
     * @return array 
     */
    function addHtmlAttribute_in_HTML_Tag(string $htmlStr, string $tagname, string $attributeName, string $attributeValue)
    {
        if(!preg_match("~<$tagname\s.*?$attributeName=([\'\"])~i", $htmlStr)){
            // if html tag attribute does not exist then add it ...
            $htmlStr = preg_replace('/(<a\b[^><]*)>/i', '$1 '.$attributeName.'="'.$attributeValue.'">', $htmlStr);
        }
        return $htmlStr;
    }

$html = '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">https://stackoverflow.com/</a>'
addHtmlAttribute_in_HTML_Tag($html, 'a', 'style', 'color:red;')


//then output will be like <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" style="color:red;">https://stackoverflow.com/</a>
?>
```