# Regex for html attributes in php

Tags: php, html, regex, php4

I am trying to parse a string of HTML tag attributes in php. There can be 3 cases:

```
attribute="value"  //inside the quotes there can be everything also other escaped quotes
attribute          //without the value
attribute=value    //without quotes so there are only alphanumeric characters
```

can someone help me to find a regex that can get in the first match the attribute name and in the second the attribute value (if it's present)?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with a regular expression? A real HTML parser is a much easier approach.

Comment: Because i'm building my own library and i can't take the code from another one

Comment: because i want to do it like this

Comment: You mean you want us to tell you how to use a glass bottle for pounding your nails? http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx

Comment: @mck89: please, don't feel attacked, it wasn't my intention. Its just that you *are* going through the this the **hard** way. Didn't attempt to offend you, just wanted to know why you couldn't use neither existing code nor an html parser.

Comment: @voyager: don't worry. Anyway i found a good solution and this is the important thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try and see if it is what you want to extract from the tags.

```
preg_match_all('/( \\w{1,}="\\w{1,}"| \\w{1,}=\\w{1,}| \\w{1,})/i', 
    $content, 
    $result, 
    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

The regex pulls each attribute, excludes the tag name, and puts the results in an array so you will be able to loop over the first and second attributes.

Comment: I found a faster and more precise solution, but i try your regex and it seems to work so it's a good starting point and i take your answer as solution. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70079532/14344959

Answer (score 9):

[Never ever use regular expressions for processing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393), *especially* if you're writing a library and don't know what your input will look like. Take a look at [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php), for example.