# Check if html contains tag with attribute

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match

I am parsing a HTML page using regex since its content is not valid HTML (open tags ect.).

I would like to check if the HTML contains an `<span>` which has the attribute `data-valmsg-for="LoginError"`. 
I have tried this using DOM, however since the HTML is not valid it doesn't seem to be able to find the tag.

The latest I have tried is `preg_match("/<[^<>]data-valmsg-for=\"LoginError\"[^<>]*>/i", $sHtml);`
My regex skills are close to non-existent, so I am wondering what the correct regex should be.

---

**Update:** 
Here is an example of the html

```
[...]
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="LoginError" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="CodeError">Du har gjort m&#229;nga f&#246;rs&#246;k inom en kort tid. F&#246;rs&#246;k igen senare</span>        <br>
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to just check it use this regexp:

```
$a = "<span></span><span data-valmsg-for=\"LoginError\">test</span><br>";
if (preg_match_all('/<[a-z \'"]*data-valmsg-for/i', $a, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

But if you need to get data from it you need following

```
$a = "<span></span><span data-valmsg-for=\"LoginError\">test</span><br>";
if (preg_match_all('/<[a-z \'"]*data-valmsg-for[^>]*>([^<]*)/i', $a, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

EDIT:

For check exact match of LoginError you need to use following:

```
$a = "<span></span><span data-valmsg-for=\"LoginError\">test</span><br>";
if (preg_match_all('/<[a-z \'"]*data-valmsg-for=[\'"]LoginError[\'"][^>]*>([^<]*)/i', $a, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

And `$matches[0]` will contains an array of all founded error texts (be carefull. Text will be taken without tags)

Comment: If I am understanding your regex, you are searching for any `span` with `data-valmsg-for`. However, I am specifically looking for `data-valmsg-for="LoginError"` since there might exist others. However, I very much like to get the contents of the span coming to think of it. I tried your regex, but can't seem to get that to work either.

Answer (score 1):

the following should work:

```
var_dump(preg_match_all('~<span\s.*?data-valmsg-for="~i', $html));
```

but domdoc should work, here's a quick example:

```
$html = <<<HTML
[...]
<span>foo</span>
<span>bar
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="LoginError" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="CodeError">Du har gjort m&#229;nga f&#246;rs&#246;k inom en kort tid. F&#246;rs&#246;k igen senare        <br>
[...]
HTML;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');

$i = 0;
foreach($spans as $span){
  echo ++$i . ' | ' . $span->getAttribute('data-valmsg-for') . '</br>';
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 | 
2 | 
3 | LoginError
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look for it. The DOMDoc doesn't work since the whole page is an APS.net page in ISS which, as usual with MS, doesn't follow html coding standards. Validating it comes with a 20-30 or so warnings.

Comment: pastebin or the like a sample of the html that's failing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70079532/14344959