# Adding a class to each paragraph tag using PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex

The `$content` variable contains a string with HTML paragraph tags such as:

```
$content = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Aliquam mauris diam, gravida eget finibus varius.</p>";
```

How can I add a class "textStyle" to **each** paragraph using PHP regex so that it looks like this:

```
$content = "<p class="textStyle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p class="textStyle">Aliquam mauris diam, gravida eget finibus varius.</p>";
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<?php

$content = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Aliquam mauris diam, gravida eget finibus varius.</p>";

    $pattern = "/(<p)/";

    $replace = '<p class="textStyle"';

    preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add attribute to first P tag using PHP regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216558/how-to-add-attribute-to-first-p-tag-using-php-regular-expression)

Comment: it doesnt work, probably i am missing something.

Comment: You should use DOM instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but you have to do this:

```
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
```

Comment: The OP's regex will match any tags beginning with "p" char and also will add class even if the tag already has one.

Comment: it's unfortunate this is the accepted answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70079532/14344959

Answer (score 8):

### Regex (not advised):

If you *must* use regex, you can try something like this. It doesn't match the abilities of DOM manipulation (see the rest of my answer below), but if you are sure your `<p>` tags are consistent without any existing classes, then you can try this:

```
$pattern = "/<p([> ])/";
$replace = '<p class="textStyle"$1';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
```

This will match only `<p>` and `<p` so as to try to keep any other attributes you may have. However, it is difficult using regex to properly handle more complicated situations like `<p id="row1" class="class1">` or `q><p` (some emoji face) .

---

### DOM Manipulation:

For a much better solution (that doesn't use regex) you can instead do the following. The reason this is superior is because you can also *replace* class attributes, and automatically maintain other attributes. Plus, if there are HTML validation errors, the `DOMDocument` object will note these.

```
<?php

$content = "<p class=\"oldClass\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p style=\"color:red\">Aliquam mauris diam, gravida eget finibus varius.</p>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

// Evaluate P tags in HTML. This just shows
// that you can be more selective on your tags
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->evaluate("//p");

// Loop through all the found tags
foreach ($tags as $tag) {

    // Set class attribute        
    $tag->setAttribute("class", "textStyle");
}

// Save the HTML changes
$content = $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Result:**

```
<p class="textStyle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<p style="color:red" class="textStyle">Aliquam mauris diam, gravida eget finibus varius.</p></p>
```

Pay special attention to this bit:

```
loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

without this, you will end of up HTML wrapper tags.

Comment: Never try to parse XML/HTML using regex.

Comment: The OP asked a specific question with a given string. He didn't say if it was for a whole page or not. I agree with you in general, but for a small string (as I stated), he might be fine.

Comment: Just FYI: in case p tag already has class attribute or the tag name is followed by a newline, this regex will not do a good job.

Comment: I've changed my vote now. (I still think you should remove any regex "solution" at all though) One thing though - wouldn't `foreach` on `getElementsByTagName` be simpler here?

Comment: I do NOT think that the regex solution should be removed. 
The question is "Adding a class to each paragraph tag using PHP Regex [closed]"

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it with DOM:

```
<?php

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML("<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>\n<p>Aliquam mauris diam, gravida eget finibus varius.</p>");

$list = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('p');

foreach($list as $p){
    $p->setAttribute('class', 'textStyle');
  }

$DOM=$DOM->saveHTML();
echo $DOM;
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/YqXOTY)

Comment: I understand you prefer a regex solution. Being a great fan of regex, I should note that changing XML  or HTML structure will force you to switch to DOM. Sooner than later, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pattern = "/<p/";
$replace = '<p class="textStyle"';
preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
```

Comment: g is implicit with preg_replace(), you don't need to include it.